# ValueError: Attempt to reuse RNNCell with a different variable scope than its first use

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following code fragment

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn

hidden_size = 100
batch_size  = 100
num_steps   = 100
num_layers  = 100
is_training = True
keep_prob   = 0.4

input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, num_steps])
lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True)

if is_training and keep_prob < 1:
    lstm_cell = rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell)
cell = rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell for _ in range(num_layers)], state_is_tuple=True)

_initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

iw = tf.get_variable("input_w", [1, hidden_size])
ib = tf.get_variable("input_b", [hidden_size])
inputs = [tf.nn.xw_plus_b(i_, iw, ib) for i_ in tf.split(input_data, num_steps, 1)]

if is_training and keep_prob < 1:
    inputs = [tf.nn.dropout(input_, keep_prob) for input_ in inputs]

outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state=_initial_state)
```

produces the following error:

> ValueError: Attempt to reuse `RNNCell` 
>   <`tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn_cell_impl.BasicLSTMCell` object at 0x10210d5c0> with a different variable scope than its first use. First use of cell was with scope `'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell'`, this attempt is with scope `'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell'``.
>
> Please create a new instance of the cell if you would like it to use a different set of weights.
>
> If before you were using: `MultiRNNCell([BasicLSTMCell(...)] * num_layers)`, change to: `MultiRNNCell([BasicLSTMCell(...) for _ in range(num_layers)])`.
>
> If before you were using the same cell instance as both the forward and reverse cell of a bidirectional RNN, simply create two instances (one for forward, one for reverse).
>
> In May 2017, we will start transitioning this cell's behavior to use existing stored weights, if any, when it is called with `scope=None` (which can lead to silent model degradation, so this error will remain until then.)

How to solve this problem?

My version of Tensorflow is 1.0.

Comment: could you solve this? I'm stuck at the same with tensorflow 1.1

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8191#issuecomment-292881312, I am not working on this issue by far, see if the link above can help you out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As suggested in the comments my solution is:
changing this

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(state_size, state_is_tuple=True)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=0.8)
rnn_cells = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell for _ in range(num_layers)], state_is_tuple = True)
outputs, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn_cells, x, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state, scope = "layer")
```

into:

```
def lstm_cell():
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(state_size, reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)
    return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=0.8)

rnn_cells = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for _ in range(num_layers)], state_is_tuple = True)
outputs, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn_cells, x, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)
```

which seems to solve the reusability problem. I don't fundamentally understand the underlying problem, but this solved the issue for me on TF 1.1rc2
cheers!

Comment: It also changes what the code *does*.  LSTM and [NAS](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.01578.pdf) cells aren't equivalent.

Comment: @Ray true, but this is only due to copy paste. the code above works with lstm cell. I just happened to work with NAS cells